# MySQL sequentially split results based on 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql

I'm displaying results from a MySQL table based on matching values in one column. I then need to separate these results based on the data in another column, when that data is different.

Here's a cut down example of the table I'm drawing data from:

```
customer_id customer_timestamp  customer_order customer_email
         27 2019-02-23 02:52:41 ABC123456789   admin@admin.com
         28 2019-02-23 02:52:41 ABC123456789   admin@admin.com
         32 2019-02-26 05:51:41 CBA987654321   admin@admin.com
```

From the above, I need to return all rows with the same customer_email then separate them by customer_order number.
Can this be achieved through a select statement alone and if so how?

Here's an example of a select statement I'm using which returns all rows with the same email;

```
$select = "select * from mytable where customer_email='admin@admin.com'";
```

The data I'm getting from the query is being fetched in an array so I need the array to generate a new loop based on the customer_order column.

Comment: `WHERE customer_email = :email AND customer_brownie_count = 47`

Comment: In addition, you should make use of prepared statements here instead of directly inserting input into the query. Check out PDO (better than mysqli_* imo, but avoid mysql_*)

Comment: what do you mean by separate? what should the result look like? - maybe it's enough to add `order by customer_order_number` to your query?

Comment: @cypherabe I'm using an array to fetch the results of the query so I need to generate another loop when customer_order is different.

Comment: you can't get several result sets out of one query execution. You either need to query for each combination of customer_email and customer_order seperatly (as Rogue suggested), or need to adress the separation in the script that processes the result.... Third alternative: read up on `group by` and aggregation functions in SQL, if you just need for example the overall price of one order

Comment: Sounds rather like you want to use GROUP_CONCAT to put the reselts for each email address into a single row.

Comment: I can fix this, from what has been said the only way is to first retrieve the customer_order numbers then group them by customer_order, display those grouped orders as a clickable button, then when the button is clicked launch a new query based on the value of that button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, might look a bit hacky but it works. I rolled back the idea of initially displaying any order data, now it requires user interaction to select a grouped order number to display details from that specific order.

Code below;

```
// Retrieve order number/s
$select_order = "select * from mytable where customer_email='admin@admin.com' group by customer_order";
$connect_order = mysqli_query($con, $select_order);
while ($row_order=mysqli_fetch_array($connect_order)) {
$customer_order = $row_order['customer_order'];
echo "
<form method='post'>
<input type='submit' value='$customer_order' name='order_current[]'>
</form>
";
}

// Make each grouped order number a separate query
if (isset($_POST['order_current'])) {
$order_all = $_POST['order_current'];
foreach ($order_all as $order_post) {

// Retrieve selected order details
$select_order = "select * from mytable where customer_email='admin@admin.coml' and customer_order='$order_post'";
$connect_order = mysqli_query($con, $select_order);
while ($row_order=mysqli_fetch_array($connect_order)) {
$name = $row_order['customer_name'];
$amount = $row_order['customer_amount'];

// Display selected order details
echo "
$name<br/>
$amount<br/>
";
}
}
}
```